# Seg Fault when using pthread_create

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, pthreads

I am having difficulty creating thread when using pthread_create, I have tried changing functions to void* and such but it keeps throwing a segmentation fault.

Any help towards fixing this problem would be appreciated, I have tried researching this problem but to no avail I have yet to find a solution

Here is my code below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <getopt.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

void readSudoku(int x[][9], FILE *in);
void printSudoku(int x[][9]);
int validateRows(int x[9][9]);
int validateCols(int x[9][9]);
int validateSubGrids(int x[9][9]);
void *vr(int x[9][9]);
void *vc(int x[9][9]);
void *vs(int x[9][9]);
bool validSudokuGrid(int x[][9]);

/* These are the only two global variables allowed in your program */
static int verbose = 0;
static int use_fork = 0;

// This is a simple function to parse the --fork argument.
// It also supports --verbose, -v
void parse_args(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int c;
    while (1)
    {
        static struct option long_options[] =
            {
                {"verbose", no_argument, 0, 'v'},
                {"fork", no_argument, 0, 'f'},
                {0, 0, 0, 0}};
        int option_index = 0;
        c = getopt_long(argc, argv, "vf", long_options, &option_index);
        if (c == -1)
            break;

        switch (c)
        {
        case 'f':
            use_fork = 1;
            break;
        case 'v':
            verbose = 1;
            break;
        default:
            exit(1);
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    // Commented this out because this will be used later
    // parse_args(argc, argv);

    // if (verbose && use_fork) {
    //     printf("We are forking child processes as workers.\n");
    // } else if (verbose) {
    //     printf("We are using worker threads.\n");
    // }

    // printf("Test");

    // Initializing sudoku grid to parse file grid
    int sudoku_grid[9][9];

    if (argc == 1)
    {
        printf("File successfully opened!\n");
    }

    readSudoku(sudoku_grid, stdin);
    printSudoku(sudoku_grid);
    // validateRows(sudoku_grid);
    // validateCols(sudoku_grid);
    if (validSudokuGrid(sudoku_grid))
    {
        printf("The input is a valid Sudoku. \n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("The input is not a valid Sudoku. \n");
    }

    return 0;
}

void readSudoku(int x[][9], FILE *in)
{
    fseek(in, -1, SEEK_CUR); // Seek to start off the current position of the file ptr

    char entry;
    int i, j, totalVals = 0;

    while ((fread(&entry, 1, 1, in)) > 0 && totalVals < 81)
    { // Read 81 digits from stdin file
        if (entry != '\n')
        { // Ignore newline
            if (isdigit(entry))
            {
                ++totalVals;
                x[i][j] = entry - '0'; // Store integer representation
                ++j;
                if (j == 9)
                {
                    j = 0;
                    ++i;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

void printSudoku(int x[][9])
{
    int i = 0, j = 0; // i = rows, j = cols
    for (i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < 9; j++)
        {
            // if we are on the third or fifth number of sub-grid
            // we make a space between nums
            if (2 == j || 5 == j)
            {
                printf("%d   ", x[i][j]);
            }
            // if we are on the last num of row we make a space
            else if (8 == j)
            {
                printf("%d\n", x[i][j]);
            }
            // anything else we make a space
            else
            {
                printf("%d ", x[i][j]);
            }
        }
        // if we are on row 3 or row 5 we make a space
        if (2 == i || 5 == i)
        {
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
}

// Used to validate rows per 3x3 grid
int validateRows(int x[9][9])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i += 3)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 9; j += 3)
        {
            int subgridValidate[9] = {0};

            for (int k = i; k < i + 3; k++)
            {
                for (int m = j; m < j + 3; m++)
                {
                    int currVal = x[k][m];
                    if (subgridValidate[currVal - 1] == 0)
                    {
                        subgridValidate[currVal - 1] = 1;
                    }
                    // else
                    // {
                    //     // printf("row: %d, col: %d", k+1, m+1);
                    //     // printf("Row: %d does not have required values \n", k + 1);
                    //     // printf("Column: %d does not have required values \n", m + 1);
                    //     return 0;
                    // }
                    else if((subgridValidate[currVal - 1] == 1) && (k >= 0 && k <=2)) {    // checks for dupes, segfaults if num > 9
                        if( m >= 0 && m <= 2 ){
                            printf("Row: %d does not have required values (either a duplicate or value not in range of 1 - 9) \n", k + 1);
                            return 0;
                        }
                        else if ( m >= 3 && m <= 5 ){
                            printf("Row: %d does not have required values (either a duplicate or value not in range of 1 - 9) \n", k + 1);
                            return 0;
                        }
                        else if ( m >= 6 && m <= 8 ){
                            printf("Row: %d does not have required values (either a duplicate or value not in range of 1 - 9) \n", k + 1);
                            return 0;
                        }
                    }
                    else if((subgridValidate[currVal - 1] == 1) && (k >= 3 && k <=5) ) {    // checks for dupes, segfaults if num > 9
                        if( m >= 0 && m <= 2 ){
                            printf("Row: %d does not have required values (either a duplicate or value not in range of 1 - 9) \n", k + 1);
                            return 0;
                        }
                        else if( m >= 3 && m <= 5 ){
                            printf("Row: %d does not have required values (either a duplicate or value not in range of 1 - 9) \n", k + 1);
                            return 0;
                        }
                        else if( m >= 6 && m <= 8 ){
                            printf("Row: %d does not have required values (either a duplicate or value not in range of 1 - 9) \n", k + 1);
                            return 0;
                        }
                    }
                    else if((subgridValidate[currVal - 1] == 1) && (k >= 6 && k <=8)) {    // checks for dupes, segfaults if num > 9
                        if( m >= 0 && m <= 2 ){
                            printf("Row: %d does not have required values (either a duplicate or value not in range of 1 - 9) \n", k + 1);
                            return 0;
                        }
                        else if( m >= 3 && m <= 5 ){
                            printf("Row: %d does not have required values (either a duplicate or value not in range of 1 - 9) \n", k + 1);
                            return 0;
                        }
                        else if( m >= 6 && m <= 8 ){
                            printf("Row: %d does not have required values (either a duplicate or value not in range of 1 - 9) \n", k + 1);
                            return 0;
                        }
                    }
                    else //all subgrid have correct values.
                    {
                        return 1; // true
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

// Validating columns in the 3x3 grid *BACK UP*
// Fixing column tracking
// int validateCols(int x[9][9]) {
//     int col = 0;
//     // Traversing Rows
//     for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
//         // Initialzing array to detect for duplicate values
//         int colValidate[9] = {0};
//         // Traversing columns
//         for(int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
//             // Holds current value depending on row / col
//             int currVal = x[i][j];

//             // If the index is filled with a zero
//             // that means the index is not taken
//             if(colValidate[currVal - 1] == 0) {
//                 colValidate[currVal - 1] = 1;   // fill index with 1 (true)
//             } else {    // Checks if dupllicate or out of bounds
//                 printf("Column: %d does not have the required values\n", j + 1);
//                 return 0;
//             }
//         }   col ++;
//     }
// }

// Function to check 3x3 Sub-Grids
int validateCols(int x[9][9])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i += 3)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 9; j += 3)
        {
            int subgridValidate[9] = {0};

            for (int k = i; k < i + 3; k++)
            {
                for (int m = j; m < j + 3; m++)
                {
                    int currVal = x[k][m];
                    if (subgridValidate[currVal - 1] == 0)
                    {
                        subgridValidate[currVal - 1] = 1;
                    }
                    // else
                    // {
                    //     // printf("row: %d, col: %d", k+1, m+1);
                    //     // printf("Row: %d does not have required values \n", k + 1);
                    //     // printf("Column: %d does not have required values \n", m + 1);
                    //     return 0;
                    // }
                    else if((subgridValidate[currVal - 1] == 1) && (k >= 0 && k <=2)) {    // checks for dupes, segfaults if num > 9
                        if( m >= 0 && m <= 2 ){
                            printf("Column: %d does not have required values (either a duplicate or value not in range of 1 - 9) \n", m + 1);
                            return 0;
                        }
                        else if ( m >= 3 && m <= 5 ){
                            printf("Column: %d does not have required values (either a duplicate or value not in range of 1 - 9) \n", m + 1);
                            return 0;
                        }
                        else if ( m >= 6 && m <= 8 ){
                            printf("Column: %d does not have required values (either a duplicate or value not in range of 1 - 9) \n", m + 1);
                            return 0;
                        }
                    }
                    else if((subgridValidate[currVal - 1] == 1) && (k >= 3 && k <=5) ) {    // checks for dupes, segfaults if num > 9
                        if( m >= 0 && m <= 2 ){
                            printf("Column: %d does not have required values (either a duplicate or value not in range of 1 - 9) \n", m + 1);
                            return 0;
                        }
                        else if( m >= 3 && m <= 5 ){
                            printf("Column: %d does not have required values (either a duplicate or value not in range of 1 - 9) \n", m + 1);
                            return 0;
                        }
                        else if( m >= 6 && m <= 8 ){
                            printf("Column: %d does not have required values (either a duplicate or value not in range of 1 - 9) \n", m + 1);
                            return 0;
                        }
                    }
                    else if((subgridValidate[currVal - 1] == 1) && (k >= 6 && k <=8)) {    // checks for dupes, segfaults if num > 9
                        if( m >= 0 && m <= 2 ){
                            printf("Column: %d does not have required values (either a duplicate or value not in range of 1 - 9) \n", m + 1);
                            return 0;
                        }
                        else if( m >= 3 && m <= 5 ){
                            printf("Column: %d does not have required values (either a duplicate or value not in range of 1 - 9) \n", m + 1);
                            return 0;
                        }
                        else if( m >= 6 && m <= 8 ){
                            printf("Column: %d does not have required values (either a duplicate or value not in range of 1 - 9) \n", m + 1);
                            return 0;
                        }
                    }
                    else //all subgrid have correct values.
                    {
                        return 1; // true
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

// Needs intense fixing
int validateSubGrids(int x[9][9])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i += 3)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 9; j += 3)
        {
            int subgridValidate[9] = {0};

            for (int k = i; k < i + 3; k++)
            {
                for (int m = j; m < j + 3; m++)
                {
                    int currVal = x[k][m];
                    if (subgridValidate[currVal - 1] == 0)
                    {
                        subgridValidate[currVal - 1] = 1;
                    }
                    // else
                    // {
                    //     // printf("row: %d, col: %d", k+1, m+1);
                    //     // printf("Row: %d does not have required values \n", k + 1);
                    //     // printf("Column: %d does not have required values \n", m + 1);
                    //     return 0;
                    // }
                    else if((subgridValidate[currVal - 1] == 1) && (k >= 0 && k <=2)) {    // checks for dupes, segfaults if num > 9
                        if( m >= 0 && m <= 2 ){
                            printf("The top left subgrid does not have the required values (either a duplicate or value not in range of 1 - 9)\n");
                            return 0;
                        }
                        else if ( m >= 3 && m <= 5 ){
                            printf("The top mid subgrid does not have the required values (either a duplicate or value not in range of 1 - 9)\n");
                            return 0;
                        }
                        else if ( m >= 6 && m <= 8 ){
                            printf("The top right subgrid does not have the required values (either a duplicate or value not in range of 1 - 9)\n");
                            return 0;
                        }
                    }
                    else if((subgridValidate[currVal - 1] == 1) && (k >= 3 && k <=5) ) {    // checks for dupes, segfaults if num > 9
                        if( m >= 0 && m <= 2 ){
                            printf("The left subgrid does not have the required values (either a duplicate or value not in range of 1 - 9)\n");
                            return 0;
                        }
                        else if( m >= 3 && m <= 5 ){
                            printf("The left mid subgrid does not have the required values (either a duplicate or value not in range of 1 - 9)\n");
                            return 0;
                        }
                        else if( m >= 6 && m <= 8 ){
                            printf("The left right subgrid does not have the required values (either a duplicate or value not in range of 1 - 9)\n");
                            return 0;
                        }
                    }
                    else if((subgridValidate[currVal - 1] == 1) && (k >= 6 && k <=8)) {    // checks for dupes, segfaults if num > 9
                        if( m >= 0 && m <= 2 ){
                            printf("The bottom left subgrid does not have the required values (either a duplicate or value not in range of 1 - 9)\n");
                            return 0;
                        }
                        else if( m >= 3 && m <= 5 ){
                            printf("The bottom mid subgrid does not have the required values (either a duplicate or value not in range of 1 - 9)\n");
                            return 0;
                        }
                        else if( m >= 6 && m <= 8 ){
                            printf("The bottom right subgrid does not have the required values (either a duplicate or value not in range of 1 - 9)\n");
                            return 0;
                        }
                    }
                    else //all subgrid have correct values.
                    {
                        return 1; // true
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

void *vr(int x[9][9]) {
    validateRows(x);
}
void *vc(int x[9][9]) {
    validateCols(x);
}
void *vs(int x[9][9]) {
    validateSubGrids(x);
}

bool validSudokuGrid(int x[][9])
{
    int numThreads = 2;
    pthread_t tid [2];

    for(int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
        if(i == 0) {
            pthread_create(&tid[i], NULL, vr(x), NULL);
        } else if(i == 1) {
            pthread_create(&tid[i], NULL, vc(x), NULL);
        } else {
            pthread_create(&tid[i], NULL, vc(x), NULL);
        }
        printf("OOOGA BOOGA");
    }
    printf("OOOGA BOOGA");
    for (int i = 0; i < numThreads; i++) {
    pthread_join(tid[i], NULL);
    printf("Thread %10x joined\n", tid[i]);
    fflush(stdout);
}

    printf("All Four Threads have exited using join(), exiting program....\n");
    fflush(stdout);
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);

    return validateRows(x) + validateCols(x) + validateSubGrids(x); // if all true = valid 9x9, else = not valid 9x9
    // return validateSubGrids(x);
}
```

Comment: What does your compiler tell you about your code? `pthread_create(&tid[i], NULL, vr(x), NULL);` It should give a warning about parameter type mismatch. It should also warn about not returning any value from `vr` and similar functions. Turn up your warning level. Read your warnings. And fix them. Only then you should even try to run your code.

Comment: code compiles successfully but gives segmentation fault either way

Comment: As I wrote: Turn up your warning level. I get `test3.c:425:43: warning: ISO C forbids passing argument 3 of ‘pthread_create’ between function pointer and ‘void *’ [-Wpedantic]` and `note: expected ‘void * (*)(void *)’ but argument is of type ‘void *’` and `warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]` and many more. For GCC use `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`

Comment: What value do you think, `vr(x)` will pass to `pthread_create`?

Comment: "code compiles successfully" No it does not, if your compiler is set to be a standard C compiler. 3 errors 8 warnings with gcc/Linux.

Comment: regarding: `int i, j, totalVals = 0;` and `++j;`  the variable `j` is not initialize  so the code is trying to increment an uninitialized variable.  this is undefined behavior.  suggest: fix azll the problem exposed via the compiler error messages then post an edit to the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pthreads expect a callback function of the form `void* func (void*)`, period. You cannot invent your own function format and expect it to work.

Furthermore the `vr(x)` etc parameters are *function calls* - you call the function once then use the result of that to tell `pthread_create` that it's a pointer to a callback function, which it isn't - it's just nonsense.

Also a function with a return type must always `return` something.

All of these problems could be avoided early on by configuring the compiler correctly, so that it gives errors upon encountering blatant bugs and invalid C, see [What compiler options are recommended for beginners learning C?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/282565) Correct use of functions is very fundamental stuff and something you need to grasp before moving on to more advanced topics like multi-threading.

Correct use, as was told in the friendly [man](https://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_create):

```
void* vr (void* x) {
    validateRows(x);
    return NULL;
}

...

pthread_create(&tid[i], NULL, vr, x);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if your code compiles but if it does then what will happen is this: When the program runs, then in pthread_create() function, it will call your function vr() and use the return value of vr() as the pointer to the function that should be called when the thread is created.

But vr() does not return any value but it is not of significance here.

The return value of any function is stored somewhere (register, etc.) according to the system. Let's assume that the return value is stored in a register called A. So, vr(x) will be called and then the value in register A will be read and the code will then assume that this value is the pointer to the function that should be called. But A can have any value (because the function vr(x) doesn't return any value and hence it didn't update A) - 0x0, 0x1, 0x75745, etc. And mostly this will be an invalid address (may be it will point to a restricted memory area, or to read only memory, etc.) and so the hardware will raise a memory access violation interrupt/signal which then results in segmentation fault.

Run the following code and you will understand what I am saying.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

void *f(void *g)
{
    printf("Called f().\n");
}

void *x(void *v)
{
    printf("Called x().\n");
    return (void *)(f);
}

int main(void)
{

    pthread_t pt;

    pthread_create(&pt, NULL, x((void *)5), NULL);

    // join pthread.
    pthread_join(pt, NULL);

    return 0;

}
```

Both functions x() and f() will get called when you run the above code.

The output will be:

Called x().
Called f().